# Copy items in StringCollection to a listbox

Tags: string, vb.net

I'm trying to copy all the strings in a string collection variable to a listbox.
I'm trying to code like this:

```
Listbox1.Items.AddRange(<strings stored in StringCollection1>)
```

So how do I copy the strings from StringCollection to a listbox using the AddRange method?

Comment: Why not just assign the collection to the `DataSource` of the `ListBox`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh! DataSource? I never knew of that. How do I add the string collection to the DataSource of the listbox?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ya I got it. I found out how to do it. Thanks. I had actually deleted my previous comment before you replied. Maybe it wasn't deleted for you.

Comment: @Somanna You should close out the question if this comment answered it for you

Comment: Hey @Somanna, it's totally fine to answer your own question and select that answer as the correct one if you found a solution. Would you be willing to do that so others can benefit from your solution? Thanks!